# Child div ignoring parent width without using white-space nowrap

Tags: html, css

For a very specific use case, I have :

- a parent div with a **fixed width**
- a child div with an **unknown width** AND a **max-width**

Here is a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/t9xUV/

CSS:

```
.parent{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.child{
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">dddd ddddddd dddddddd ddddddddddddd ddddd dddddddddd ddddddd dddddddd dddddddddddd
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the child to take its own width, ignoring the parent width.

I tried :

- `position:absolute` for the child but the words are wrapped regarding the parent width
- `white-space: nowrap` for the child but the max-width property is then "ignored" by the words

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution : http://jsfiddle.net/t9xUV/1/

Just set this css property to the child element :

```
  margin-right:-999999px;
```

Source : [Forcing Block Elements to Not Wrap in IE (no fixed width parent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125086/forcing-block-elements-to-not-wrap-in-ie-no-fixed-width-parent)